# Joomla backup doesnt show the same on my local machine

Tags: backup, wampserver, joomla3.0

I have backed up my online joomla site (with Akeeba) and then try to have a version of my site on the wamp(local machine). the problem is after extraction(and kickstart) the site some up but not exactly same as my online version. menues are not in the same order and horizantal but vertical and the footer and image slider stopped working.
I really appreciate any help regardin this issue please.
Thnaks

Comment: Can you show the difference in code that the back up causes or at least how the page looks before and after back up?

Comment: I am using Shaper Helix theme which u can check here [link](http://demo.joomshaper.com/2013/helix-ii/) but when I backed up the blue colour part are not there an also the menu is not like that but like plain unordered list.any idea

Comment: Did you restore your site into a sub folder of the `\wamp\www` folder?

Comment: Yes I restored all to \wamp\www and all except the one i mentioned function properly